# openfire rest api plugin always response 403 Forbidden

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I enable the REST API plugin at the plugins page at openfire admin page

And send a GET request to following url by Postman which is an extension of chrome:

http://my.host.com:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users

And I get this response

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials → true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → origin, content-type, accept, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Content-Length → 0
Date → Mon, 24 Aug 2015 08:41:42 GMT
```

I don't know what's wrong in my steps. Could anyone tell me?

Thanks very much

Comment: Are you sure that you get 403 and not 401? Which means that your provided header authorization is not in place or wrong.

Answer (score 8):

by "enable" the REST API, you may mean "installed" the plugin. because after you successfully installed it. You will have to go to "Server Settings" -> "REST API", and check "Enabled". You may also choose "HTTP Basic Auth" or "Secret key auth" there, then save your changes.
[Documentation](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#authentication)

Answer (score 0):

you can't simply just visit the api address, must add  authorization to your request header in code:

```
 httprequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:theSecretKeyInConfigPage");
```

you can using fidder to mock a httprequest :

```
GET http://yourdomain.com:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/sessions HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: yoursecretkey
Host:yourdomain.com:9090
```